# Subscript out of Range on Declared Range Variable?

Tags: excel, vba, range

I'm having trouble with this bit of code. I had tied it to a command button in a different workbook for testing prior to moving it to the final workbook. I get a Runtime Error (9) at the declaration for Comp_F. I genuinely can't figure out what is wrong and I assume it will effect all of the "Cost Calculation" worksheet references.

I have ensured there is a worksheet in the workbook with the proper name, even the case is exact, and at this point I'm not sure what to do with it. Thanks a bunch folks!

```
Declarations:

Dim Prod_Lead_Time As Range
    Set Prod_Lead_Time = Worksheets("Output").Range("H4")
Dim Customer_Owned As Range
    Set Customer_Owned = Worksheets("Output").Range("I4")
Dim Prep_Lead_Time As Range
    Set Prep_Lead_Time = Worksheets("Output").Range("H5")
Dim Fill_Lead_Time As Range
    Set Fill_Lead_Time = Worksheets("Output").Range("H6")
Dim Lab_1_Lead_Time As Range
    Set Lab_1_Lead_Time = Worksheets("Output").Range("H7")
Dim Lab_2_Lead_Time As Range
    Set Lab_2_Lead_Time = Worksheets("Output").Range("H8")
Dim Ship_Lead_Time As Range
    Set Ship_Lead_Time = Worksheets("Output").Range("H9")
    Ship_Lead_Time = 1
**Dim Comp_F As Range
    Set Comp_F = Worksheets("Cost Calculation").Range("Q5:Q44")**
Dim Comp_Grams As Range
    Set Comp_Grams = Worksheets("Cost Calculation").Range("N5:N44")
Dim Comp_Conc As Range
    Set Comp_Conc = Worksheets("Cost Calculation").Range("B7:B46")
Dim Comp_Reactive As Range
    Set Comp_Reactive = Worksheets("Cost Calculation").Range("T7:T46")
Dim Input_Grade As Range
    Set Input_Grade = Worksheets("Input").Range("C2")
Dim Part_Number As Range
    Set Part_Number = Worksheets("Input").Range("C1")
Dim Comp_Names As Range
    Set Comp_Names = Worksheets("Input").Range("B13:B52")
Dim Grade_List As Range
    Set Grade_List = Worksheets("Grade").Range("C4:C14")
Dim Output_Fuel_Ox As Range
    Set Output_Fuel_Ox = Worksheets("Output").Range("C45")
Dim Output_TechReview As Range
    Set Output_TechReview = Worksheets("Output").Range("H3")
    
Dim Reactive As Boolean
Dim Fuel_Ox As Boolean
Dim Require_Lab2 As Boolean
    Require_Lab2 = False

Dim LEAD_TIME As Double
    LEAD_TIME = 5 'Minimum time allowed
Dim Labor_Time As Double
Dim Gram_Factor As Double
Dim Fill_Diff As Double
Dim Assay_Diff As Double
Dim Total_Lab_Lead_Time As Double

Dim Grade_Row As Variant

Dim Comp_Number As Integer

'These constants are derived mathematically, contact Dan Bartel for clarification on values or equations used
Const Numerator As Double = 0.883
Const GramEXP As Double = 0.115
Const Scaler As Double = 3.013362081
Const Comp_EXP As Double = -0.453870512
Const Customer_Owned_Time As Integer = 9
Const Reactive_Mix As Integer = 3
Const FuelOx_Mix As Integer = 2
```

Main_Works:

```
If CheckBox1.Value = True Or Application.WorksheetFunction.Right(Part_Number, 1) = "C" Then
    Customer_Owned = "Customer Owned"
End If
    
Grade_Row = Application.Match(Input_Grade, Grade_List, 0)

If IsEmpty(Input_Grade) = True Or IsError(Grade_Row) = True Then 'Will end the sub if no grade is entered and prompt the user to enter one prior to running any calculations
    MsgBox ("The product grade is required to calculate lead time")
    GoTo LastLine
End If

'Finds number of components in part
Comp_Number = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Comp_Names, Not "")

'Pulls the relevant data for the grade of the part and stores for lead time calculation
Fill_Diff = Cells(Grade_Row, 4)
Assay_Diff = Cells(Grade_Row, 5)

For i = 1 To 40 'Finds one of the variab;e values necessary to calculate lead time
    Gram_Factor = Gram_Factor + Comp_F(i) * Numerator / (Comp_Grams(i) ^ Comp_EXP)
Next

Labor_Time = Gram_Factor * Scaler * (Comp_Number ^ Comp_EXP) * Sqr((Fill_Diff + Assay_Diff) / 2)

LEAD_TIME = LEAD_TIME + Labor_Time

If Application.Sum(Worksheets("Cost Calculation").Range("T7:T46")) > 0 Then
    Reactive = True
    LEAD_TIME = LEAD_TIME + Reactive_Mix
End If

Do Until Require_Lab2 = True Or i = 41 'If there is a reactive component with a concentration <=0.01% a second Lab analysis is required
    If IsEmpty(Comp_Reactive(i)) = False And Comp_Conc(i) <= 0.01 Then
        Require_Lab2 = True
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop

If Output_Fuel_Ox = "Yes!!!" Then 'Output message for fuel ox mixtures is used
    Fuel_Ox = True
    LEAD_TIME = LEAD_TIME + FuelOx_Mix
End If
```

Logic_For_Lead_Time:

```
'Prep, Fill, Lab time
If Grade_Row = 6 Then 'EPA Non-Reactive
    Prep_Lead_Time = 1
    Fill_Lead_Time = 2
    Lab_1_Lead_Time = 3
ElseIf Grade_Row = 7 Then 'EPA Reactive
    Prep_Lead_Time = 1
    Fill_Lead_Time = 2
    Lab_1_Lead_Time = 2
Else
    Prep_Lead_Time = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(LEAD_TIME * 0.1, 0)
    Fill_Lead_Time = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(LEAD_TIME * 0.35, 0)
    
    Total_Lab_Lead_Time = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(LEAD_TIME - Prep_Lead_Time - Fill_Lead_Time - Ship_Lead_Time, 0)
    
    Lab_1_Lead_Time = Total_Lab_Lead_Time
End If

If Require_Lab2 = True Then
    Lab_1_Lead_Time = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(Total_Lab_Lead_Time * 0.6, 0)
    Lab_2_Lead_Time = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(Total_Lab_Lead_Time * 0.4, 0)
End If

'Customer Owned Cylinder factor
If Customer_Owned = "Customer Owned" Then
    Prep_Lead_Time = Prep_Lead_Time + Customer_Owned_Time
End If

Prod_Lead_Time = Prep_Lead_Time + Fill_Lead_Time + Lab_1_Lead_Time + Lab_2_Lead_Time + Ship_Lead_Time

If Prod_Lead_Time > 25 Then
    Output_TechReview = "TECH REVIEW NEEDED"
End If
```

Comment: Best to declare what workbook that sheet is in too.

Comment: check the spelling of the sheet and make sure you are still refering to `ThisWorkbook`

Comment: @ScottCraner it is still out of range even with "ThisWorkbook" or any other declaration of the workbook it is in. I even closed all the other workbooks I had open just to sure. It seems as though it very specifically does not like the "Cost Calculation" sheet. I tried to declare it as "Sheet11" and that didn't work either.

Comment: Make sure there are no extra spaces or other unseen characters in the sheet name that you are missing in the vba.

Comment: @ScottCraner that was the problem! The dang sheet in excel had a space after it. Thanks a bunch man! I can't believe that didn't occur to me